# Ionic 3 issue in color of label of item in list

Tags: list, listview, ionic-framework, colors

In my Ionic 3 project I've implemented a simple list like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-dossiers',
  templateUrl: 'dossiers.html'
})

export class DossiersPage {

  public heroes;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    this.heroes = [
    {id: 1, name:'Superman'},
    {id: 2, name:'Batman'},
    {id: 5, name:'BatGirl'},
    {id: 3, name:'Robin'},
    {id: 4, name:'Flash'}
    ]; 
  }
}
```

And than in the HTML:

```
<ion-content>

    <ion-list>
        <button ion-item *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
                  {{ hero.name }}
                </button>
    </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Now I've a problem with the rendering of the list, because the color of the label of each item is white and I don't see anything.

How I can solve this issue?

This is the result:

- [this is how the items are displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXxSy.png)
- [this is what I see if I touch the item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Kph.png)

PS: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Inspect the button in chrome to see who set the color and where.

Comment: thanks. the reason was that the css for another plugin overrides the css of app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you edited the .scss file inside the page folder?

if not try adding a color="primary" or color="secondary" to your button tag.